# Using Scala 2.10 implicit classes to convert to "built-in" standard library classes

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I am trying to use the new Scala 2.10 `implicit class` mechanism to convert a `java.sql.ResultSet` to a `scala.collection.immutable.Stream`. In Scala 2.9 I use the following code, which works:

```
/**
 * Implicitly convert a ResultSet to a Stream[ResultSet]. The Stream can then be
 * traversed using the usual methods map, filter, etc.
 *
 * @param resultSet the Result to convert
 * @return a Stream wrapped around the ResultSet
 */
implicit def resultSet2Stream(resultSet: ResultSet): Stream[ResultSet] = {
  if (resultSet.next) Stream.cons(resultSet, resultSet2Stream(resultSet))
  else {
    resultSet.close()
    Stream.empty
  }
}
```

I can then use it like this:

```
val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM foo")
resultSet.map {
  row => /* ... */
}
```

The `implicit class` that I came up with looks like this:

```
/**
 * Implicitly convert a ResultSet to a Stream[ResultSet]. The Stream can then be
 * traversed using the usual map, filter, etc.
 */
implicit class ResultSetStream(val row: ResultSet)
  extends AnyVal {
  def toStream: Stream[ResultSet] = {
    if (row.next) Stream.cons(row, row.toStream)
    else {
      row.close()
      Stream.empty
    }
  }
}
```

However, now I must call `toStream` on the `ResultSet`, which sort of defeats the "implicit" part:

```
val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM foo")
resultSet.toStream.map {
  row => /* ... */
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Should I still be using the `implicit def` and `import scala.language.implicitConversions` to avoid the "features" warning?

**UPDATE**

Here is an alternative solution that converts the `ResultSet` into a `scala.collection.Iterator` (only Scala 2.10+):

```
/*
 * Treat a java.sql.ResultSet as an Iterator, allowing operations like filter,
 * map, etc.
 *
 * Sample usage:
 * val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("...")
 * resultSet.map {
 *   resultSet =>
 *   // ...
 * }
 */
implicit class ResultSetIterator(resultSet: ResultSet)
extends Iterator[ResultSet] {
  def hasNext: Boolean = resultSet.next()
  def next() = resultSet
}
```

Comment: you forgot the "val" before (row :ResultSet) :D

Comment: before, you transform with your function the resultSet to a Stream. now, to do the same things, you must call toStream. implicit class are not implicit function. Personnaly, I prefer the second method with implicit class and "forced" call to toStream. If you really want "map", you must defined a "map" function in your implicit class who will be a wrapper around Stream

Comment: Actually, I think having a `toStream` method is better than an invisible implicit.

Comment: Yeah, good point. I have always been leery of all of the implicit conversions in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a reason here to use implicit classes. Stick to you first version. Implicit classes are mainly useful (as in "concise") to add methods to existing types (the so called "enrich my library" pattern).
It is just syntactic sugar for a wrapper class and an implicit conversion to this class.

But here you are just converting (implicitly) from one **preexisting** type to another **preexisting** type. There is no need to define a new class at all (let alone an implicit class).

In your case, you **could** make it work using implicit classes by making `ResultSetStream` extend `Stream` and implementing as a proxy to `toStream`. But that would really a lot fo trouble for nothing.